# Is it possible to get Windows Authentication in ASP.NET without enabling it in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, plugins, windows-authentication

#### Background

Our asp.net webapp has grown and now has 6 different methods of authentication, with more on the horizon. I want to standardize these methods and extract each into an independent plugin which can be disabled/enabled at will (and possibly even configured from within the app). That's also necessary because at least one of the methods is client-specific and uses a DLL supplied by said client, which should not be distributed to other clients.

#### Problem

As I'm trying to create a plugin mechanism for authentication methods, I'm faced with a particular method which is Windows Authentication. Normally it works by enabling Windows Authentication in IIS, but since it should be an independent plugin I'd like to avoid it modifying web.config and/or IIS config. So, assuming that Windows Authentication is turned off by default in IIS (only anonymous for everything), is there any way I can get my plugin to work? Can I somehow tell IIS from within my ASP.NET application that I'd like to get Windows authentication on a particular URL/request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using advapi32 you should be able to get the details without having to use Windows Authentication.

Have a look at it here:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser

Other than that, there is no alternative to user Windows Integrated Auth to get further user details

Comment: That uses just username/password, not NTLM. Perhaps I was not clear in the original topic, but with "Windows Authentication" I mean the kind of "Windows Authentication" that IIS performs, which (at least on IE) happens transparently to the user.

Comment: As far as I'm aware then, No. I'm sure your clients shouldn't have issue with enabling a feature on the server that is required.

Comment: All I wanted was to make the plugin independent of current IIS configuration.

Comment: No one would re implement the complexity of that feature as it already exists. Your best best would be to make changes to the web.config from your component, even though as you said you don't want to.

Comment: It's not even so much web.config as IIS itself. But, OK, I'll accept that it's necessary.

Comment: No worries, apologies for depressing you so early in the day heh.